# What should be done after renaming the urls of my website?

Tags: google, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

One month ago, I updated all the product URLs on my site which were separated by `_` sign to be separated by `-` sign.

Example:

```
.com/Calipers/Insize_1108
```

now looks like

```
.com/Calipers/Insize-1108
```

There were nearly 1200 links updated, and it is showing in webmaster tools as crawl errors. I marked them as fixed, I resubmited my sitemap but it didn't work, they are still showing in google search results.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have set up 301 (Permanent) redirects from your old URLs to the new as soon as you changed them. Do this now to correct all the crawl errors and Google (and other search engines) will update their index to the new URLs. How quickly this happens will depend on Google's crawl rate of your site.

With a 301 redirect in place then anyone following an old URL in the SERPs will still end up at the correct place.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't happen immediate. rebuild the sitemap.Delete the old one.
go to the reindex area and add your url & sub pages to see if that helps.

Comment: As I indicated in my question, I have already rebuild sitemap one month ago and resubmited. It doesn't make sense to me waiting for rubish urls to be removed by itself. It is like not cleaning my room until my mum realizes and cleans it, and I live in mess for days. Can't I remove my room by myself? Or at least call my mum ?